# Try create my own Struct via Ruby

Tags: ruby, struct, metaprogramming

I can't inherit the Struct. I must implement class which act like Struct.
Is there a way improve my code for use "ClassName" and functional like Struct ? And write k=Dave.new("Rachel" , "Greene")  ???

```
class MyStruct
  def self.new(*attributes)
    puts "ppp"
    dynamic_name = "ClassName"
    Kernel.const_set(dynamic_name,Class.new()  do
      attributes.each do |action|
        self.send(:define_method, action) {
          puts "call #{action}" 
        }
      end  
    end
    )
  end
end

# class ClassName
  # def new *args 
    # puts "iii"
  # end
# end



Dave = MyStruct.new(:name, :surname)

k=Dave.new()     # k=Dave.new("Rachel" , "Greene")
k.surname
k.name
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a version of your code which works:

```
class MyStruct
  def self.new(*attributes)
    Class.new do
      self.send(:attr_accessor, *attributes)
      self.send(:define_method, :initialize) do |*values|
        values.each_with_index { |val, i| self.send("#{attributes[i]}=", val) }
      end  
    end
  end
end

Dave = MyStruct.new(:name, :surname)
k = Dave.new('Rachel', 'Green')
# => #<Dave:0x00000001af2b10 @name="Rachel", @surname="Green"> 
k.name
# => "Rachel"
k.surname
# => "Green"
```

1. You don't need to `const_set` inside the method - `Dave =` is enough
2. I'm creating here an [`attr_accessor`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Module/attr_accessor) for each of the attributes, so you are getting a getter and a setter for each
3. In the `initialize` method I'm sending each value to its corresponding setter, to set all values. If there are less values than anticipated, the last attributes will not be set, if there are more - an exception will be thrown (`undefined method '='`)

Comment: WoW ! Thank you so much. Good luck for you!

Comment: Sorry If I bother you. Why I can't write k["name"] ?

Comment: A small thing: `self.send` can be written `send`.

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at the Struct class in Ruby?

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Struct.html

```
class MyStruct < Struct.new(:first_name, :last_name)

end

MyClassObj = MyStruct.new("Gavin", "Morrice")
```

Also, you shouldn't ever overwrite `self.new`, define initialize instead

Comment: Sorry , but for my task I can't inherit the Struct. I must implement class which act like Struct.

Comment: Isn't "shouldn't ever" a bit extreme?  Suppose, for example, you wanted to compile a list of class instances in a class instance variable?  I would view that as a job for the class, so would put it in `new`, rather than have instances invoke `self.class.instance_variable_get...` and `...set` in `initialize`.